Getting Webpack 2 module parse error while trying to load launchdarkly-js-client-sdk
I am getting following error while trying to load launchdarkly-js-client-sdk using webpack 2:
ERROR in ./~/launchdarkly-js-client-sdk/dist/ldclient.es.js
Module parse failed: node_modules/launchdarkly-js-client-sdk/dist/ldclient.es.js Unexpected token (1:3500)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
File content to load from node_module/launchdarkly-js-client-sdk/dist/ldclient.es.js
https://unpkg.com/launchdarkly-js-client-sdk@3.4.0/dist/ldclient.min.js
webpack loader config:
{
    test: /\.es\.js$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: [{
            presets: [['babel-preset-env']]
        }]
    }]
}

error after above config:
ERROR in ./~/launchdarkly-js-client-sdk/dist/ldclient.es.js
Module build failed: Syntax Error: node_modules/launchdarkly-js-client-sdk/dist/ldclient.es.js Unexpected token, expected ( (1:37325)

As I can check from the error it looks like Webpack 2 is unable to parse the ldclient.es.js file from the launchdarkly-js-client-sdk package.
This mainly happens when Webpack doesn't have the appropriate loader configured to handle the file type or syntax.
so could you please share the file of the code to get more closer look into this.
